# How to successfully move a Visual studio project to a new PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, office-addins

Returning to Visual studio after a few years away and really stuck with this one.
I inherited an Excel addin project  for calling rest services that needs a few tweaks. No problem with code. It uses the NetOffice component which seems quite useful for handling COM interop.
It was on a windows 8 machine 32 bit visual studio 2013 community. I am on windows 10 64 bit Visual studio 2015 community fresh install.

I tried copying all the project files to my PC, open solution file and go:
Just once, the first time, it ran and paused on my breakpoint, but never after that. it still runs on other persons pC- not too big a surprise.
It even complained after the build that did not have permission to unregister the dll from (the old PC)
A text search of the project for the old PC name found nothing.

Edited all references and paths in properties file. Opened solution and project files in notepad and satisfied that nothing now points to previous machine.
It builds again but fails to stop on breakpoints. Then it complains that it can't find the login properties in the login file on (you guessed- the old PC)

I tried building a new project from existing files. That seemed to go well, but it failed to add references and I can't even find the references via add reference dialogue, Most peculiar it complains that a sub namespace of system does not exist.  I tried different target .net frameworks without any luck and gave up on this approach.
I suspect part of the problem might be connected to my using 2015 community edition and the template might not be installed that was originally used ti build it.I used a class library when I attempted to build a new project manually.

Is there a safe procedure for inheriting a project like this and getting it set up cleanly on a new PC?

I realise this is a fairly dumb newbie question, but I am really stuck now.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can begin to search for the missing references on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/). If you didn't find them check the list of the VS extensions installed on the original PC, if a custom template was installed, it should appear there.

Comment: Check to make sure you are building as x86 not As Any. Sometimes hard to find references since it could be looking for a 64 bit dll

Comment: Are you on the latest update (Update 3)?  This sounds a bit like VS 2015 RTM issues.  You find the latest here:  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129   (Info here:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) .  Also make sure you move over just the source files, not any binaries - it should still work, but recompiling locally should absolutely work.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use same version of Visual Studio on destination PC than you can just copy/paste your project to the destination PC... but as chandler mentioned the best way to to that is to use some kind of **source control** like **GIT** or **TFS (Team Foundation Server)**, with source control method it will be less painful for you to accomplish that movement of projects.

And if you choose the Team Foundation Server you have unlimited number of free repositories as long you are a small team up to five members.

Please see pricing models and additional information here: [Visual Studio Team Services Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/pricing/visual-studio-team-services-pricing-vs)